Pass parameters to quarto_render
Please have a look at the script below. I have used it many times when rendering rmarkdown files.
The rmarkdown file fiches_automatic.Rmd contains a parameter called "state" which is used in the computations.
The script iterates the rendering of the markdown file and each time passes a different value of the "state" parameter, so that I get automatically a bunch of parametrized reports.
This does not work when I render a quarto file and I use quarto_render().
Can anyone translate this function into something I can use when acting on a quarto qmd file which has again this "state" parameter?
render_one <- function(state) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    'fiches_automatic.Rmd',
    output_file = paste0(state, '_report.docx'),
    params = list(state = state),
    envir = parent.frame()
  )
}

state.name <- c("AUT", "BEL", "BGR", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DNK", "ESP", "EST", "FIN",
"FRA", ## "GBR",
"GRC", "HRV", "HUN", "IRL", "ITA", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MLT",
"NLD", "POL", "PRT",
"ROM", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE")


for (state in state.name) {
    render_one(state)
  }


Did you read this nice blog? https://meghan.rbind.io/blog/2022-09-25-tips-for-custom-parameterized-pdfs-in-quarto/#rendering-parameterized-reports   Let me know where it did not work, I made a successful similar test a some time ago.

I am not ashamed to say I got some help from chatgpt.
I tested the script below, and it works. The only trick is that in my quarto file I need to pass the "state" parameter as params$state.
# Load the Quarto library
library(quarto)

render_one <- function(state) {
  quarto::quarto_render(
    input = 'fiches_automatic.qmd',  # Specify the Quarto file
    output_file = paste0(state, '_report.docx'),  # Output filename
    execute_params = list(state = state),  # Parameters to pass
    execute_dir = getwd()  # Set the working directory for the rendering process
  )
}




state.name <- c("AUT", "BEL", "BGR", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DNK", "ESP", "EST", "FIN",
                "FRA", ## "GBR",
                "GRC", "HRV", "HUN", "IRL", "ITA", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MLT",
                "NLD", "POL", "PRT", "ROM", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE")




for (state in state.name) {
  tryCatch({
    render_one(state)
  }, error = function(e) {
    message(paste("Error in rendering report for", state, ":", e))
  })
}

